# Addition of Vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How do you explain in general the addition of any two vectors geometrically without reference to any coordinate system?

Comment: You're sticking a vector parallel to $\mathbf{B}$ to the end of $\mathbf{A}$, and then considering the vector with initial point that of $\mathbf{A}$ and terminal point that of (the copy of) $\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: I think paralleogram law of addition can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to remember that vectors describe translations, that is moving without rotating. The arrow just shows for a single point where that point ends up after the movement. The addition of the two vectors is just the result of doing both translations one after another; the resulting translation can then again be described by an arrow that starts at an arbitrary point, and ends where that point ends up after doing that combined movement.

This method has the advantage that it doesn't matter whether the arrows start at the same point, and that it is obvious that it doesn't matter where the arrow starts; all arrows with the same length and direction describe the same vector, because they describe the same translation.

Also from this, one naturally gets the common description of vector addition by starting the second arrow at the end of the first one; the natural explanation being "this point is moved to there by the first translation, and then further to over there by the second translation; the sum arrow goes from the starting point directly to the final end point".

Comment: your answer has made it clear for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to check wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the starting point of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are coincident, $\vec{A} + \vec{B}$ is the vector from that common starting point to the far corner of the parallellogram which has as two of its sides $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$.

There is no need for a coordinate system in this definition.  The coordinate system comes about when you start saying things like $\vec{A} = <2,3>$.  ($2$ what?  $3$ what?)

Comment: Actually i did not intend to ask the question "How do you explain the addition of vectors geometrically without reference to any coordinate system?" taking into consideration the example that goes along with it. I have edited the question. Please take a look.

Comment: My answer still addresses your question. You introduce a coordinate system precisely when you start talking about components of the vector. There is none before that. A parallelogram is a parallelogram regardless of the coordinate system, or even where there is one or not.

Comment: As you said that "A⃗ +B⃗  is the vector from that common starting point to the far corner of the parallellogram which has as two of its sides A⃗  and B⃗ " . Is there any way to prove that sum of the vectors is indeed the diagonal of the parallelogram whose  adjacent sides are the 2 vectors that are being added.

Comment: That's one way that vector addition can be defined.  There's no need for a coordinate system if it's defined this way.  Or ... vector addition can be defined in terms of the componentwise sum of ordered pairs.  That works too, and in *that* cases there's no need for a graphical analog.

Comment: "That's one way that vector addition can be defined."
How was this definition arrived at or is there any method to prove it?

Comment: you don't prove definitions. You can prove that two definitions are equivalent, or prove that something you've defined satisfies some other nice properties you wanted (e.g. prove that this geometric definition of addition is commutative, associative). But it makes no sense to ask for a proof of a definition.

Comment: Sorry for framing the question in wrong way. But the first part of the question "How was this definition arrived at" was still valid. I think @celtschk has provided us with the correct answer.